# Random characters when describing kubernetes namespaces

Tags: dns, namespaces, kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-deployment

I'm trying to connect my Kubernetes deployments together via DNS.

I have a Java (Spring Boot) deployment and a javascript (node.js) deployment, both exposed via a default ClusterIP Service. I need websocket and REST communication between both services.

I've read that I should use DNS so that these two services can talk to each other, but I'm having trouble trying to determine what those DNS's are.

For example,

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

gives me this:

`NAMESPACE      NAME
default        javascript-deployment-65869b7db4-mxfrb
default        java-deployment-54bfc87fd6-z8wml`

1. What do I need to specify in my Service config to stop these random suffixes being applied?
2. How do I then determine what my DNS names need to be with a similar form of my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local?

Answer (score 0):

About your questions:

1- Kubernetes doesn't recommend to avoid creating the names because basically, it ensures that the pods are unique and also, the first part of the hash it groups all the pods with the same replica-controller.

So just as advice, don't touch it. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#pod-template-hash-label

2- `kubectl get services -o wide` will provide you in which port is your app listening. You just need to use the cluster ip + port like CLUSTER_IP:PORT to be able to reach your service.

Comment: Ok, so there should be a way to access the service pointing at my node.js deployments from my Spring Boot containers. What environment variable should I look for? I read that something similar to JAVASCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_SERVICE_HOST might be possible (based on the service names I described in my question). Is this correct? Does Kubernetes inject this env var by default?

Comment: if you have both services running in the same namespace you just need to use the service name.
If the Java app wants to talk with the Nodejs app you must call the following URL (assuming that your nodejs service name is "nodejs":
http://nodejs

If they're in different namespaces, you need to use the FQDN:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: Ok, is there a way to inject the service name dynamically? And do I need to specify the port also?

Comment: there's no way to inject it dynamically because it works as a real DNS,  you cannot inject the DNS dynamically, you need somehow to know the name or the domain.
No, you don't need the port.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using the Service metadata name and port.

For example, this is my service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-big-deployment
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
selector:
  app: my-service
```

From my applications in the cluster I can now access this service via the following environment variables:

```
MY_BIG_DEPLOYMENT_SERVICE_HOST
MY_BIG_DEPLOYMENT_SERVICE_PORT
```